# How to disable blinking caret when editing text in OS X?

Tags: macos, text-cursor

Blinking cursor when editing text has been driving me crazy. Is there any way to disable it or at least make it blink less frequently?
Using OS X 10.8.1.

Typing the following in terminal didn't help:

```
defaults write -g NSTextInsertionPointBlinkPeriod -int 100000000    
defaults write -g CursorBlink -string 0
```

Answer (score 13):

This works for me (*in 10.8 and earlier versions of OS X*):

```
defaults write -g NSTextInsertionPointBlinkPeriod -float 4000000000
```

It doesn't take effect until you quit and reopen applications, and it doesn't apply to text views in web views, iWork applications, Mail, Notes, TextMate, or BBEdit. The value is in milliseconds.

Edit: changing NSTextInsertionPointBlinkPeriod stopped working in 10.9, but there are now new preference keys that have the same effect:

```
defaults write -g NSTextInsertionPointBlinkPeriodOff -float 0
defaults write -g NSTextInsertionPointBlinkPeriodOn -float 4000000000
```

They only apply to the same views as NSTextInsertionPointBlinkPeriod though.

Comment: It works for me only in a few text inputs, but in most of them it doesn't, e.g. text area it Super User (using Safari) or any other site, or text edit, etc. In most of the places where I need it to work, it doesn't work. I have rebooted my system after making the change in the terminal.

Comment: It works with TextEdit on my account, but not with form controls in web views.

Comment: Sorry, it indeed works with TextEdit, but doesn't work with other text editor I am using (TextMate).

Comment: TextMate is a little special, it doesn't use the default TextView but its own variant, which is why it doesn't inherit these defaults. @Atern

Comment: Is there any way to disable blinking cursor in form controls in web browsers and in Apple Mail?

Comment: Note that the value `999999999999` is actually invalid and is dangerous to set! It may cause some apps to crash, see [this issue](https://github.com/VsVim/VsVim/issues/2809#issuecomment-611889782) for example. The maximum allowed value for this setting is `4294967294`, and you shouldn't set it to be bigger than that.

Comment: This approach did not work in the Mail.app

Answer (score 1):

Bug filed:

- Chrome – http://crbug.com/175101
- Webkit – http://webk.it/109281

---

In Firefox, open `about:config` and create new integer `ui.caretBlinkTime` with the value of `0`

Comment: +1 for filing the bugs. Do note that this isn't an answer to the question though, so it shouldn't really have been posted as an answer, but as a comment. (Unfortunately, I believe Stack still doesn't let new users post comments for some reason I can't understand.)

Answer (score 0):

For text, that's hard. I use:

```
defaults write -g NSTextInsertionPointBlinkPeriod -float 10000
defaults write -g NSTextInsertionPointBlinkPeriodOn -float 10000
defaults write -g NSTextInsertionPointBlinkPeriodOff -float 10000
```

with NeoOffice and Textedit. It also works with Bean and some other applications. It does not work with LibreOffice or Pages, or did not work last I tried them.

For email, I use Thunderbird, opening about:config and creating ui.caretBlinkTime 0

For the web, I use Waterfox with the same fix. You may also be able to use Firefox.